# Is it possible to utilise ggfortify outside of autoplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

Blog posts such as [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_lm.html) describe `ggfortify` as a good way to use `ggplot` to chart `lm` objects.  However, they only seem to add it to the `autoplot` command.  I would like to know somewhat what's being charted and the like, so I'm trying to avoid the `autoplot` shortcut.

Is there another way to utilise this functionality, without this shortcut?  Or is the shortcut the best way?

Comment: You can call `fortify` (which is almost the same as `broom::augment`) on the model to extract the data and plot it normally with ggplot. If you're looking for what those plots are, check out `?plot.lm` (after which they're modeled).

Comment: @alistaire Yes, thanks, that's pretty much what I was after.